# Is there any methods to generate such a random table in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to generate a table of random numbers for the location allocation problem, for example like this:

|  | Capacity | Fixed cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Warehouse 1 | 9927 | 415379 |
| Warehouse 2 | 10189 | 419745 |
| Warehouse 3 | 9111 | 401781 |
| Warehouse 4 | 8259 | 387590 |

the capacities are random numbers between (8000, 12000) and the fixed costs are between (35000, 42000), but how can I ensure that for example, **when the capacity of Warehouse 1 < Warehouse 2, the fixed cost of Warehouse 1 is also smaller than Warehouse 2?**

Comment: One option would be: Generate four random capacities. Generate four random fixed costs. Sort both lists. Shuffle pairs of (capacity, fixed costs) to the four warehouses.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by applying the same random seed to both ranges in a linear fashion,

```py
import random
import math

nrows = 10
rows = []


for warehousen in range(1, nrows):
    seed = random.random()

    capacity = math.floor(seed * (12000 - 8000)) + 8000
    fixedCost = math.floor(seed * (42000 - 35000)) + 35000

    rows.append(["Warehouse " + str(warehousen), capacity, fixedCost])

print(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.random.randint(8000,12000,size=10)]).T, columns=['Capacity'])
>>> df
   Capacity
0     11966
1     11899
2      9662
3     10393
4      9922
5     10790
6      9926
7     10894
8      8211
9      8912

>>> df['Fixed Cost'] = df['Capacity'].astype(float) * np.random.normal(4, 35)
>>> df.sort_values('Capacity')
   Capacity    Fixed Cost
8      8211  37909.022099
9      8912  41145.439647
2      9662  44608.083244
4      9922  45808.466358
6      9926  45826.933790
3     10393  47983.006536
5     10790  49815.899214
7     10894  50296.052459
1     11899  54935.994879
0     11966  55245.324374
```

You are essentially saying there is relationship between cost and size. That's where the multiples 4 and 35 come from.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a library for this but you can simply do this -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

capacity = np.random.randint(8000, 12000, size=5)
fc = np.random.randint(35000, 42000, size=5)

capacity = np.sort(capacity)
fc = np.sort(fc)

X = np.vstack((capacity, fc))
np.random.shuffle(X)

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure pandas solution, along the lines of what @HanseHirse suggested as comment:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

amount = 4
df = pd.DataFrame({"Capacity": sorted(random.choices(range(8000, 12000), k = amount )),
                   "Fixcosts": sorted(random.choices(range(35000, 42000), k = amount ))},
                   index=[f"Warehouse {n+1}" for n in range(amount)])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
             Capacity  Fixcosts
Warehouse 1      8556     35485
Warehouse 2     10216     35608
Warehouse 3     11231     37113
Warehouse 4     11251     38603
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

warehouses = 4

index = [f'Warehouse {i+1}' for i in range(warehouses)]
columns = ['Capacity', 'Fixed cost']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
capacity = np.random.randint(low=8000, high=12000, size=warehouses)
idx = np.searchsorted(np.sort(capacity), capacity)
fixed_cost = np.sort(np.random.randint(low=35000, high=42000, size=warehouses))[idx]
df['Capacity'] = capacity
df['Fixed cost'] = fixed_cost
```